# What is the Festina Lente Regime?

Tags: photons, laser, bose-einstein-condensate, cooling

I am studying BEC formation without evaporative cooling, so realized only thrpugh optical means.

One of the problems to face is "photon reabsorption": an atom absorbs a photon of the laser used for cooling and spontaneously re-emits it, then if the atomic sample is very dense, the photon can be reabsorbed by other atoms, heating the sample.
The *Festina Lente Regime* should suppress this heating, and consists in setting a trap frequency $\omega_0$ than the spontaneous emission rate $\Gamma_s$.
$$
\omega_0\gg \Gamma_s
$$

The process is described [here](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.80.5305), and also [here](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.85.4249) in a more qualitative way.

I really can not understand how this festina lente regime works in a "simple way" from these articles, why it succeedes in supressing heating.

I ask for a simple explanation of this regime, or a reference in which it is explained clearly. Calculations are welcome, but also just a qualitative picture is appreciated.

Comment: Festina Lente in latin language is a proverb meaning "hurry up slowly". It is a saying which means "you should do things well and diligently, because too much haste will mess things up, and it will cost you time". But I don't know physical details.

Answer (score 0):

The "festina  lente" (FL) regime is when the spontaneous emission/absorption rate $R_{\mathrm{sat}}$ is smaller than the trap frequency $\omega$.

A qualitative and intuitive way of understanding this is as follows. If the absorption rate is smaller than the trap frequency, then the time $\tau_s$ taken to absorb one photon from the trap light is much longer than the time to perform an oscillation in the trap $\tau = 2\pi/\omega$, so $\tau \gg \tau_s$. That is, you need to "make" a lot of trap oscillations before you absorb a photon and hence see the ensuing heating effects. This just meant you have to wait quite a while to start seeing the effects of absorption, and so you can usually neglect them.

To be more mathematical, the spontaneous emission/absorption rate $R_{\mathrm{sat}}$ is given by:
$$ R_{\mathrm{sat}} = \frac{\Gamma}{2}\frac{I/I_{\mathrm{sat}}}{1+I/I_{\mathrm{sat}}+(2\Delta/\Gamma)^2} ,$$ where $\Gamma$ is the natural linewidth of the atomic state, $I$ the incident intensity, $I_{\mathrm{sat}}$ the saturation intensity for the transition, and $\Delta$ the detuning between laser frequency and atomic transition.

You can already see that is goes as $1/\Delta^2$, i.e. far-detuned light will cause very little absorption. That's why, for traps, you choose very far detuned light.

For a typical cold atoms / BEC experiment, let's use the $D2$ line of $^{87}$Rb, and a trap light of $1064$ nm. Typically, a BEC emerges for trap frequencies on the order of $\omega \sim 10-100$ Hz.

Using a $1$ W and $100$ µm waist beam, typical for optical dipole traps, the scattering rate $R_{\mathrm{sat}}$ is $\sim 1.6\times 10^{-5}$ Hz.

So indeed, $\omega \gg R_{\mathrm{sat}}$.